# Form.Show() is not setting focus on the form

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, show

I have searched but not found or found but nothing has worked for me, hence this question. Following code is used to show a progress-form on top of my main form. This form has to have focus.

### Code:

```
private ProgressForm _progress;

private void ShowProgress(string message)
{
    Enabled = false;
    _progress = new ProgressForm(message, this);
    _progress.Show();
}
```

The form is shown but it does not have focus, see below image:

[image: Incorrect]

As you can see the main form still has its focus and not the new form. What I want is this:

[image: Correct]

I have tried following methods, but neither of them worked:

```
_progress.BringToFront();
_progress.Focus();
_progress.Activate();
```

I have also tried these methods from within the constructor of the new form but this gave the same result. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

### Edit:

I used the solution proposed in the answer by 'gnarlybracket', only had to switch to lines of code to make it work. Also important, I found out why `ShowProgress` was not focusing. I called the method from the form's `Load` event. If I call it from the form's `Activated` event, the new form is shown and had focus.

Comment: If you don't want people to be able to click the main form, try using .ShowDialog()

Other than that, I can't work out why .Focus() wouldn't work. Odd.

Comment: `ShowDialog()` is not an option, see my comment on 'gnarlybracket's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
_progress.Show();
```

try:

```
_progress.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Good try but after I show the progress-form, I have to start a `BackGroundWorker` and when I use `ShowDialog()` the code is hanging at this line and not starting the worker.

Comment: Can you start the `BackgroundWorker` first, and immediately after use `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I also found why at first `Show` didn't work. I've put it in my question as an edit.